# Create edge list by iterating through pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following dataframe:

```
User_ID Retweet_UserID
001     005
001     002
001     003
001     002
002     007
002     001
003     002
```

User_ID is the user identification number and Retweet_UserID is the User_ID of the user who authored the original tweet. I need to create a retweet network (edge list) between users in my User_ID column. I mean, I only care about a retweet if it is between two User_IDs in my User_ID column. For example, the retweet between user 001 and user 005 is not important for me because user 005 is not among the users in User_ID column. So the edge list should look like this:

```
Source  Target   Weight 
001     002      2
001     003      1
002     001      1
003     002      1
```

So basically, I want two things: drop any entry that has a `Target` that is not in `Source` and then you want to have the number of times you have the tuple `(Source, Target)`. My dataframe is so large and I'm looking for a pandas way to do it fast.

Comment: So basically, you want to things: drop any entry that has a `Target` that is not in `Source` and then you want to have the number of times you have the tuple (`Source`, `Target`). Please say so in your question.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Just edited the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to filter (as pointed out by Brad Solomon):

```
filtered = df[df['Retweet_UserID'].isin(df['User_ID'].unique())]
```

Now you need to do a `groupby` and `size` to get the total number of retweets between pairs of people:

```
result = filtered.rename(columns={'User_ID': 'Source', 'Retweet_UserID': 'Target'}) \
                 .groupby(['Source', 'Target']) \
                 .size() \
                 .reset_index(name='Weight')
```

Then `result` is (given your sample):

```
   Source  Target  Weight
0       1       2       2
1       1       3       1
2       2       1       1
3       3       2       1
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're looking to *filter the rows based on whether `Retweet_UserID` falls in the set of unique IDs from `User_ID`*:

```
>>> unique = df.User_ID.unique()
>>> filt = df[df.Retweet_UserID.isin(unique)]
>>> filt
   User_ID  Retweet_UserID
1        1               2
2        1               3
4        2               1
5        3               2
```

If you'd like to create a new column of indicators:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> df['Weight'] = np.where(df.Retweet_UserID.isin(unique), 1, 0)
>>> df
   User_ID  Retweet_UserID  Weight
0        1               5       0
1        1               2       1
2        1               3       1
3        2               7       0
4        2               1       1
5        3               2       1
```

Comment: Many thanks. I added df.groupby(['User_ID','Retweet_UserID'],as_index = False).agg({'Weight':'sum'}) to count duplicated rows.